# Linking WorkItem to a Azure Devops Wiki Page Programmatically Issue

Tags: azure, azure-devops

When i link a workitem in Azure Devops GUI i can see WorkItem link in Wiki Page as follows:
[image]

Also in WorkItem's Links you can see the link to page as "Wiki Page" name. so bidirectionally you can access wikipage and workItem.

My need is to Link WorkItem to Wiki Page With Azure Devops Api (because the automation process of creating wiki page).
Successfully My Wiki Page linked to workItem. but wiki page does not show the workitem linked!
am i missing something? should i somewhere else to link workitem to wiki page?

i linked workitem as follows:

```
    $workItemUri = "$orgUrl/$ProjectName/_apis/wit/workitems/$WorkItemID?$apiVersion"
    $wikiRelationUrl = 'vstfs:///Wiki/WikiPage/' + $wikiPagePath
    $relationBody = '
    [
      {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/relations/-",
        "value": {
          "rel": "ArtifactLink",
          "url": "'+ $wikiRelationUrl + '",
          "attributes": {
            "name": "Wiki Page"
          }
        }
      }
    ]' 

    $wiResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $workItemUri -body $relationBody -Headers $headers -Method Patch -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($wiResponse.count -eq 0) {
        Write-Host "Relation to WorkItem added successfully."
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Relation to WorkItem already exists."
    }
```

result:

[image]

But in wikik page there is no effect of WorkItem on wiki page.

Comment: @MiaoTian-MSFT thanks for your answer. i read your answer and couldn't find any mistake as you mentioned. so, my question is open.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find error from your code. But I can add the wiki link to the work item successfully with the following sample. And the work item will show in the wiki page.

[image]

```
$PAT=""
$orgUrl="https://dev.azure.com/orgname"
$WorkItemID="11"
$apiVersion="api-version=7.2-preview.3"


$PATGetBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$PAT")
$Authentication = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($PATGetBytes)
$Headers = @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $Authentication) }


$workItemUri = "$orgUrl/_apis/wit/workitems/"+$WorkItemID+"?$apiVersion"

$wikiRelationUrl = "vstfs:///Wiki/WikiPage/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$relationBody = '
    [
      {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/relations/-",
        "value": {
          "rel": "ArtifactLink",
          "url": "'+ $wikiRelationUrl + '",
          "attributes": {
            "name": "Wiki Page"
          }
        }
      }
    ]' 
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $workItemUri -Method PATCH -Headers $Headers -Body $relationBody -ContentType 'application/json-patch+json'
$response | ConvertTo-Json
```